# Why does sync on treestore not nest nodes

Tags: extjs

I am using a treepanel with a treestore and treemodel with 3 levels of nodes. I want to add nodes to the store and then sync the store via the server api. All is looking good for the reading of the nested store. Here is an example of the data when I send a get to the server api:

```
{
"children" : [{
        "region" : 1,
        "label" : "Paris",
        "children" : [{
                "schoolId" : 1,
                "type" : "elementry"
                "address" : "1 rue generale",
                "children" : [{
                        "classId" : 1,
                        "teacher" : "Smith",
                        "year" : 1,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 2,
                        "teacher" : "Alan",
                        "year" : 1,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 3,
                        "teacher" : "Larkin",
                        "year" : 2,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 4,
                        "teacher" : "Sharp",
                        "year" : 2,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "schoolId" : 2,
                "type" : "elementry"
                "address" : "1 rue de gaulle",
                "children" : [{
                        "classId" : 5,
                        "teacher" : "Mathew",
                        "year" : 1,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 6,
                        "teacher" : "Mark",
                        "year" : 1,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 7,
                        "teacher" : "Luke",
                        "year" : 2,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 8,
                        "teacher" : "John",
                        "year" : 2,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "schoolId" : 3,
                "type" : "middle"
                "address" : "99 avenue de larre",
                "children" : [{
                        "classId" : 7,
                        "teacher" : "Lisa",
                        "year" : 5,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }, {
                        "classId" : 8,
                        "teacher" : "Bart",
                        "year" : 6,
                        "leaf" : true
                    }]
            }]
    }]
}
```

However when I add a child node and send the sync command, the resulting post request is not nested. Code to append child node:

```
var store = me.getViewModel().getStore('schoolStore');
var region = new WEBI.model.Region({
                    "label" :"Bordeaux"                                 
                });
var school = new WEBI.model.School({
                    "type" : "elementry",                   
                    "address" : "10 rue Bidart"     
                });
region.appendChild(school);
store.root.appendChild(region);
store.sync();
```

The data in the post request is in the following format:

```
[{
    "label" : "Bordeaux"
    "region" : "Region-1",
    "parentId" : "root",
    "leaf" : false
}, {
    "type" : "elementry",
    "address" : "10 rue Bidart"
    "idtsl2" : "School-1",
    "parentId" : "Region-1",
    "leaf" : false
}]
```

I was expecting/hoping the post request would nest the itmes, ie have the following format

```
[{
    "label" : "Bordeaux"
    "region" : "Region-1",
    "parentId" : "root",
    "leaf" : false,
    "children" : [{
            "type" : "elementry",
            "address" : "10 rue Bidart"
            "idtsl2" : "School-1",
            "parentId" : "Region-1",
            "leaf" : false
        }
    ]
}]
```

Has anyone else seen the same problem. Is this a matter of having to just deal with having the post request in this format or is there some way I can configure my proxy/model to send the posts in a nested format?